# htmlagilitypack can only read first row

Tags: c#

I use htmlagilitypack to read a table from a html file. I only get the result from the first row. I don't know why?

html document:
[image]

Code:

```
    foreach (var cell in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class = 'borders']/tbody/tr/td"))  // finder kun den første række
    {
      result.Add(cell.InnerText);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Why do I only get the result from the first row?

Comment: Maybe because of missing `<tr>`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `//` not `/`:

```
//table[@class='borders']//tbody//tr//td
```

It gives you all rows.

Comment: The result I get is only 1 row.

Comment: @MHP Check the answer now.